# NoSuchOptError running OpenStack functional tests

Tags: openstack, tox

I'm trying to run the tox functional tests for the OpenStack Magnum project. I have a functioning DevStack environment with Magnum and I've followed the instructions [here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/magnum/dev/functional-test.html) to setup for and run the tests. The specific test I'm trying is `tox -e functional-k8s`. I get the following for 6/7 of the tests.

`oslo_config.cfg.NoSuchOptError: no such option in group auth: admin_project_name`

Trying to figure out if there's something wrong with my setup. I've asked on the IRC but it's been very quiet since the conference started. I think it might not be specific to Magnum.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using an old version of tempest, which hasn't migrate options from [identity]admin_project_name to [auth]admin_project_name, so I would suggest you to upgrade tempest version to latest, and test it again (with the proper configuration set)

My environment is:

```
$ tempest --version
tempest 11.0.1
```

It is fine to run, but I have no such backend, so it fails with invalid auth, not the NoSuchOptError.

Or you can file a bug, to ask magnum team to provide backward compatibility, or at least update the document.

Cheers!

Comment: I can't seem to update tempest. I've followed the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Tempest) and cloned the repo then ran `sudo pip install tempest/` but `tempest --version` still returns 10.0.1. I tried `sudo pip install -U tempest/` as well. Any ideas?

Comment: are you using pypi.python.org as index url for pip, the default one, can you check your ~/.pip/pip.conf to see if it is pointing to some out dated mirror of pypi?